# Deleting a Domain

Tags: mailgun

I have two domains on my mailgun account. The first domain (https://my.domain) required me to add an SPF record and a DKIM record (`pic._domainkey.my.domain`). However, the second (https://subdomain.my.domain) required me only to add an SPF record.

I would like to delete the first domain from MailGun and all of the unnecessary DNS records. However, I am worried that after doing so the second domain will be Unverified, since it might suddently require some new DKIM record (e.g. `pic._domainkey.subdomain.my.domain`).

Can anybody reassure me that removing the first domain from my MailGun account will not cause the second to be unverified?